# constexpr begin of a std::array

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I am having trouble understanding why both gcc-8.2.0 and clang-7.0.0 reject the following code (live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/RuOXN8)):

```
#include <array>

int main() {

    constexpr std::array<int,3> v{1,2,3};
    constexpr auto b = v.begin(); // error: not a constexpr 
    return 0;
}
```

with the error

```
error: '(std::array<int, 3>::const_pointer)(& v.std::array<int,3>::_M_elems)' 
is not a constant expression (constexpr auto b = v.begin();)
```

According to [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/begin), the `begin()` member function is declared `constexpr`. Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: use `.cbegin` .

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин makes no difference.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин `begin()` and `cbegin()` do the same thing on const objects.

Comment: so try `auto b=...` and then if it fails `const` . also you change `auto`  to `std::....::citerator`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

So let's sidestep `std::array` to make this a bit easier:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct array {
    T elems[N];

    constexpr T const* begin() const { return elems; }
};

void foo() {
    constexpr array<int,3> v{{1, 2, 3}};
    constexpr auto b = v.begin(); // error
}

constexpr array<int, 3> global_v{{1, 2, 3}};
constexpr auto global_b = global_v.begin(); // ok
```

Why is `b` an error but `global_b` is okay? Likewise, why would `b` become okay if we declared `v` to be `static constexpr`? The problem is fundamentally about pointers. In order to have a constant expression that's a pointer, it has to point to one, known, constant thing, always. That doesn't really work for local variables without static storage duration, since they have fundamentally mutable address. But for function-local statics or globals, they do have one constant address, so you can take a constant pointer to them.

---

In standardese, from [[expr.const]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6):

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - if the value is an object of class type, [...]
> - if the value is of pointer type, it contains the **address of an object with static storage duration**, the address past the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a function, or a null pointer value, and
> - [...]

`b` is none of those things in the second bullet, so this fails. But `global_b` satisfies the bolded condition - as would `b` if `v` were declared `static`.