# Empty std::array<T, 0> doesn't have constexpr begin()?

Tags: c++

The following code doesn't compile with clang and libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/rDL-_K

```
#include <array>
int main() {
    static constexpr std::array<int, 0> xs{};
    constexpr auto i = xs.begin();  // non-constexpr function 'begin' cannot be used in a constant expression

    return 0;
}
```

But if you change the `0` to a `1`, it compiles.

Is this a bug in libc++ or is there a good reason for it? How could I work around this if I have generic constexpr code that uses `begin`/`end`?

(I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972533/constexpr-begin-of-a-stdarray), but my example intentionally uses `static` to avoid this problem.)

Comment: I believe this is a bug in libc++ which was introduced in https://reviews.llvm.org/D41223

Comment: Is this just plain curiosity, or is there some underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: Well, I was writing real code that used begin() in a constexpr context and attempted to test it with an empty array, which failed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in libc++ which was introduced in: https://reviews.llvm.org/D41223

In particular, the `_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX14` is missing on begin(), end(), etc.

It seems to work in libstdc++: https://godbolt.org/z/xmfdot

The bug has been reported at https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40124 but it sounds like it may not be fixed due to difficulties obtaining a constexpr pointer to an object when one has not been constructed.

Comment: +1. https://libcxx.llvm.org/ says: "If you think you've found a bug in libc++, please report it using the [LLVM Bugzilla](https://bugs.llvm.org/). If you're not sure, you can post a message to the [libcxx-dev](https://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/libcxx-dev) mailing list or on IRC."